# Conductor and local Kronecker–Weber theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-fields, p-adic-numbers

Given an abelian extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, the global Kronecker–Weber theorem tells us that there exist a positive integer $N$ and a primitive $N$-th root of unity $\zeta_N$ such that $K\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N)$. Then one may ask how to find such $N$ explicitly and what is the smallest possible $N$? This question has been discussed more than once on MathStackExchange (cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3967969/185235), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/31485/185235) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36536/185235)). On the other hand, the gCFT tells us that the minimal $N$ is given by the global conductor $\mathfrak{f}(L/\mathbb{Q})$.

---

Now I'm going to ask the local analog of these two questions:

Given an abelian extension $F$ of $p$-adic rational field $\mathbb{Q}_p$, the local Kronecker–Weber theorem tells us that there exist a positive integer $N$ and a primitive $N$-th root of unity $\zeta_N$ such that $F\subseteq \mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_N)$.

1. How to find such $N$ explicitly?
2. What is the smallest possible $N$?

The answer to the first question is somehow included in the classical proof of the local Kronecker–Weber theorem: reducing to an extension with prime-power degree over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. More explicitly, A [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.05801) of J. Koenigsmann and B. Stock proves that
$$F\subseteq \mathbb{Q}_p\left(\zeta_{p^{v_p(n)+2}(p^n-1)}\right),$$
where $n=[F\colon\mathbb{Q}_p]$. Although this result has already satisfied the need for $N$ to be explicit, I wonder if we assume the acknowledgment of arithmetic information of $F$ (e.g. ramification index, inertia degree, local conductor……) the number $p^{v_p(n)+2}(p^n-1)$ can be made any smaller?

On the other hand, it is easy to see that the local conductor $\mathfrak{f}(F/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ does not give the smallest $N$ in the local case. So the second question is what can we say about the smallest $N$ in the local case?

Comment: I’m a bit surprised: why doesn’t the local conductor give you the correct power of $p$, at least?

Comment: @Aphelli hummm... Good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m$ be the order of $p \in \mathbb Q_p^\times$ in the character of $\mathbb Q_p^\times$ associated to $F$ by local class field theory.

Let $\ell$ be the least integer prime to $p$ such that the multiplicative order of $p$ mod $\ell$ is divisible by $m$.

Then the minimum value of $N$ is $\ell \mathfrak f$, where $\mathfrak f$ is the multiplicative conductor of $\mathfrak f$.

Proof: If any $N$ works, write $N = a p^b$ with $a$ prime to $p$. Then $\mathbb Z_p^\times \in \mathbb Q_p^\times$ acts trivially on the $a$th roots of unity, and any element of $\mathbb Z_p^\times$ which is $1$ mod $p^b$ acts trivially on the $p^b$th roots of unity, and thus must act trivially on $F$, implying the conductor is at most $p^b$. On the other hand, $p \in \mathbb Q_p^\times$ acts trivially on the $p^b$th roots of unity, and $p^{\operatorname{ord}_a(p)}$ acts trivially on the $p^a$th roots of unity, so $\operatorname{ord}_a(p)$ must be a multiple of $p$ and thus $a \geq \ell$. But $ N = \ell \mathfrak f$ does in fact work since $\mathbb Q_p^\times = \mathbb Z_p^\times \times \langle p \rangle$ and any element which acts nontrivially on $F$ must have a factor in $\mathbb Z_p^\times $ or $\langle p \rangle$ which acts nontrivially on $F$ and thus must act nontrivially on $\mu_{\mathfrak f}$ or $\mu_\ell$ respectively.

The bound you state then arises from bounding trivially $m$ by $n$, bounding trivially $\ell$ by $p^m-1$, and bounding trivially $\mathfrak f $ by $p^{v_p(n)+2}$.

As [Aphelli points out in the comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463715/conductor-and-local-kronecker-weber-theorem#comment1204103_463715), you can improve this slightly by replacing $p^{ v_p(n)+2}$ by $\mathfrak f$.

But any other improvement will not come from the usual invariants of local fields - e.g. none of ramification index, inertia degree, and local conductor help to bound $m$ better than the trivial $n$.

Improved bounds for $\ell$ are not local, but can come from global number theory, i.e. effective forms of the Chebotarev density theorem - it suffices to find prime $\ell$ whose Frobenius conjugacy class in the Galois group of $ \mathbb Q( \mu_m, p^{1/m}) $ is an element of order $m$ fixing $\mu_m$. But these results don't give any method that I am aware of to find $\ell$ explicitly other than a search through primes congruent to $1$ mod $m$.

Comment: Could you lose some words or give a reference about the procedure you're refering to at the beginning associating to every (finite) abelian extension $F$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (...or maybe more generally any local field $K_v$?) a character of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$? Moreover, if we take any $r \in \mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$, what means "the order" of $r$ in this character of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$? Do you mean the "the order" in group theoretic sense of *the image* of $r$ with respect to this character map?

Comment: @JackYo I mean a continuous homomorphism from $K_v^\times$ into any finite group, which is the same as an open subgroup. Reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_class_field_theory. Yes, I mean the order in the group-theoretic sense of the image of $r$ (in this case, $p$).

Comment: Yes, so that's what you mean by a character of $K_v$, a homo from $K_v^{\times}$ to some finite group. But in the answer you wrote *"the character of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$ associated to  (finite) abelian extension $F$ "*, so you refer to a machinery associating to an ablian finite extension certain character. May I assume that here you refer to $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}/N(F^{\times}) \to \text{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ coming from local reciprocity map?

Comment: @JackYo Yes, that's right.